# How to return an integer value from logical operation in PHP

Tags: php, variables, logic

I need to return an integer value not "bool" from this logical operation:

```
$x =7581749795038 ;
$y = 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF;
echo $x . "<hr>";
echo $x and $y;
```

The output is 1.

I need to return the two variables and return a value like 01011010010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `&` not `and`

[PHP Bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

You'll want to follow up with [`decbin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) to convert the integer into it's binary representation.

```
echo decbin( $x & $y );
```